# How to write shouldComponentUpdate with async update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

My React class EventTable has several modes and acording to the mode, it fetches different data from server and displays them in to a `<Table>`. I first made the class display static data and it worked just fine, including switching the mods via prop from higher component. But then I switched to dynamic data from fetch (`ApiHelper` functions in `updateData()`) and now I have a problem.

I can't figure out the right `shouldComponentUpdate` function. In the current state, the class renders before the fetch is done, so with the initial mode, it displays nothing and when the mode changes, it displays data from previous fetch.

I tried for example comparing old data with the new ones in `shouldComponentUpdate` or updating only if `eventsLoaded` is true and making it false before the fetch, but then it breaks the way, that the components updates infinitely which sometimes results in flickering when changing the mode and in server traffic spam.

```
class EventTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            eventsLoaded: false,
            data: undefined
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.updateData();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.updateData();
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextStates) {
        return this.props.mode !== nextProps.mode;
    }

    updateData() {
        if(this.props.mode === 0)
            ApiHelper.getAllEvents().then((result) => this.setState({data: result, eventsLoaded: true}));
        else if(this.props.mode === 1)
            ApiHelper.getMemberEvents(this.props.userToken).then((result) => this.setState({data: result, eventsLoaded: true}));
        else
            ApiHelper.getPastEvents().then((result) => this.setState({data: result, eventsLoaded: true}));
    }

   render() {
        //rendering a <Table> using this.state.data
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shouldComponentUpdate` isn't doing you any favors here; it's just making things harder (preventing the component from re-rendering when you set state, which is what you want). I would take it out for now and only worry about implementing it if you identify react performance as an issue, and this component in particular as a cause.

Then, you want to add the previous props vs. next props check (currently in `shouldComponentDidUpdate`) to `componentDidUpdate`, and only call `this.updateData` when the props have changed. If you don't wrap that in a conditional, it will fire after every render, which can lead to loop behavior.

With those changes in place, both an initial render and a change to the `mode` prop will trigger a call to `updateData`, which will make a request and update state, which will trigger a render. After that render, `componentDidUpdate` will fire but see that props haven't changed, so it won't try to re-fetch.

Comment: Yes! This solution works perfectly, thank you very much.